# YouTube Player stops with "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: tc" whenever ad starts

Tags: android-youtube-api

YouTube player stops whenever the advertisement plays. I have been running my app like 2 years and this problem started about couple of days ago. I did nothing to interfere advertisement, and it worked like charm during last 2 years. So I tested several phones and some of them was OK but some was NOT. If a video starts play without ad then it works fine.

YouTube App version : 11.04.56
(I tested same YouTube version at different phone and it has no problem. I guess it's not a problem of YouTube App)

Phone that problem occurs : LG G4, Android 4.4.2, Kernel 3.10.0, Build number KOT49I.F460K11c, Softwareversion : F460K11c

Here is my catlog

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: tc
>         at sz.<clinit>(SourceFile:145)
>         at ipw.e(SourceFile:250)
>         at bom.run(SourceFile:74)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
>         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

Comment: were you able to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8044) to check when it's solved, but probably a Youtube App update fix the problem, we cannot do nothing in our code.